# Integrate PayPal Express Checkout with unknown user's PayPal account

Tags: paypal

My company has a software as a back office solution. Recently we are developing a new solution which looks like an e-commerce. Our clients have their websites, but don't have a e-commerce. So we want to offer a feature in our software that can create a shop for them to attach in their websites.

The solution we are looking for is the possibility to integrate with our clients PayPal account and use their ClientID to create a PayPal Express Checkout Button (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/).

I've done something like this in another project for Slack Integration. We used a Slack Button (https://api.slack.com/docs/slack-button) which is a oauth flow that allow to use the user's credentials and interact with Slack.

The PayPal API provide something like that? Anybody have some thought about it or have done it yet?

Comment: Wouldn't the better option be to integrate with a payment gateway? You'll get PayPal, credit cards and other payment methods, and possibly also a better integration.

Comment: There's 3 personas. My Company, Our Client and the Consumer (our client's client). We want to create a transaction between the Consumer and Our Client. We need to check if this transaction is completed and valid so we can charge Our Client for that service (we will charge for quantity of sells). Can a gateway provide that kind of feature?

Comment: I'm worry about a solution that i've already figured out and just don't like it. If we ask Our Client his ClientID and Secret, our server should be able to check the transaction status via PayPal API. But is that safe to own Our Client's API Secret?

Answer (score 0):

Found this guide: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/permissions-service/integration-guide/PermissionsUsing/?mark=request%20permission

It is a flow to ask the user for permission to operations on his behalf.

So we can check transaction details...